# Set custom seaborn color palette using hex codes, and name the colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

My company has a formal color palette so I need to use these colors in my seaborn charts. I would therefore like to set the default seaborn color palette, and give these colors easy-to-use names such as 'p' for purple and 'g' for green.

Here is what I have so far for code:

```
# Required libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Wanted palette details
enmax_palette = ["#808282", "#C2CD23", "#918BC3"]
color_codes_wanted = ['grey', 'green', 'purple']

# Set the palette
sns.set_palette(palette=enmax_palette)

# Assign simple color codes to the palette
```

Please help me to assign simple names to the colors using my "color_codes_wanted" list.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question in total. You can define a  function `c = lambda x: enmax_palette[color_codes_wanted.index(x)]` and use `c("grey")` in the remainder of the code. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Interesting solution. Yes, your answer will work for my purposes. I thought there might be a built-in way of doing that (i.e. assigning simple color names to hex codes in the default palette). Thanks!

Comment: I mean, you can do a lot. What use case is there where you would like to use those colors?

Comment: For example, g = sns.distplot(x, color='official_company_green'), and have the color be my company's official green color. Like how the default seaborn colours can be used: g = sns.distplot(x, color='b')

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Use custom function

As commented you may create a function that if called with a custom colorname returns the hex color from the list.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Wanted palette details
enmax_palette = ["#808282", "#C2CD23", "#918BC3"]
color_codes_wanted = ['grey', 'green', 'purple']

c = lambda x: enmax_palette[color_codes_wanted.index(x)]

x=np.random.randn(100)
g = sns.distplot(x, color=c("green"))

plt.show()
```

#### Use the C{n} notation.

It should be noted that all colors in seaborn are matplotlib colors. One option matplotlib provides is the so called C{n} notation (with n = 0..9). By specifying a string like "C1" you tell matplotlib to use the second color from the current color cycle. `sns.set_palette` sets the color cycle to your custom colors. So if you can remember their order in the cycle you can use this information and just specify `"C1"` for the second color.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Wanted palette details
enmax_palette = ["#808282", "#C2CD23", "#918BC3"]

sns.set_palette(palette=enmax_palette)

x=np.random.randn(100)
g = sns.distplot(x, color="C1")

plt.show()
```

#### Manipulate the matplotlib color dictionary.

All named colors are stored in a dictionary you can access via

```
matplotlib.colors.get_named_colors_mapping()
```

You may update this dictionary with your custom names and colors. Note that this will overwrite existing colors with the same name.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors as mcolors
import seaborn as sns

# Wanted palette details
enmax_palette = ["#808282", "#C2CD23", "#918BC3"]
color_codes_wanted = ['grey', 'green', 'purple']
cdict = dict(zip(color_codes_wanted, [mcolors.to_rgba(c) for c in enmax_palette]))

mcolors.get_named_colors_mapping().update(cdict)
x=np.random.randn(100)
g = sns.distplot(x, color="green")

plt.show()
```

All codes shown here will produce the same plot in "the company's green" color:

[image]

Comment: Note, that for many plots with large areas, the `saturation` parameter (which defaults to .75) can affect the actual color being used. This can be very confusing to someone employing precise hex values in their palette.